# Alloy analyzer crashes on Mac OS X 10.14

Tags: alloy

I tried to use the Alloy analyzer but it crashes as soon as I try to type anything in the editor for example. Any ideas how to fix that ?

Comment: A bit more of a description (screen shots, messages) might help not to get negative points

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the problem is only related to the version bundled for Mac. Running the jar from the command line worked.